# How to define "there is just one prime number between n and m" using just logical symbols, = and *?

Tags: logic

I have defined x|y and "x is prime", but I have no idea how to do the "between" part. We cant use "belongs to (n, m)", and the > and < are undefined.

Comment: Do you have access to $+$ and either "$x$ is positive" or $\Bbb N$ itself?

Comment: How you defined $x|y$ ? And "$x$ is prime" ?

Comment: @Arthur Unfortunately not, but its assumed all of those are natural numbers.

Comment: @ALLEGRANZA x|y <=> There exists such k, that x*k=y. x is prime <=> There is no such k, that (k|x and ~(k=1) and ~(k=x)).

Comment: Ok; $1$ is there. But we need also $+$. With them, we can define: $n > m \leftrightarrow \exists k (n=m+k+1)$

Comment: Having $>$, we may define: $\text{Betw}(x,m,n) \leftrightarrow (n > x \land x > m)$.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA That's true, but I don't know how to define that +.

Comment: Your title is somewhat misleading.  You do have equality (a relation) and multiplication (a binary function).  Hence you are not only using logical symbols.  You may want to edit your question and clarify.  Also, "working with natural numbers" may be taken to mean "working in a theory of the natural numbers" in which the successor function is most likely available.  The exact wording of your problem may reveal such details.

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi Changed it.

Comment: Do you have a successor function available?  I suspect you can't define > or + without it.

Comment: @mjqxxxx I'm not really sure about it, but if that's the case, then I guess it should be. I still think that the teacher who prepared this problem just forgot to include some symbols.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Even successor isn't enough - neither $+$ nor $<$ is definable in $(\mathbb{N}; \times, Succ)$. (Remember that recursive definitions aren't first-order necessarily, so the "obvious" way to define $+$ or $>$ from $Succ$ doesn't work.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: $x+y=z \iff S(x \times z)\times S(y\times z) = S(z\times z \times S(x \times y))$ is a first-order definition of $+$ in terms of $S$ and $\times$.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working in a first-order theory with just with multiplication and identity and a zero as non-logical vocabulary, then you are working in Skolem Arithmetic.

But you can't define "between" in Skolem arithmetic.

So the proposed task can't be done.

[Why can't you define "between" in Skolem arithmetic? Because if you could, you could define the order relation "<". (For $m < n$ iff $m$ is $0$ and $n$ isn't, or else $m$ is between $0$ and $n$). And if you could define "<", you could define successor. And if you have multiplication and successor you can define addition by a neat observation of Julia Robinson's (1949). But you can't define addition in Skolem arithmetic.]

Comment: Another reason why you can't define betweenness is that permuting the primes leads to an automorphism of $(\mathbb N,0,{\times},{=})$, and such an automorphism doesn't necessarily preserve the fact that $3$ is between $2$ and $5$.

Comment: Oh that is very pretty!

Comment: @Henning: Or more generally, any such automorphism will invariably switch the order of two primes.

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned in some of the comments you need addition. Surely your metalanguage should encompass something at least as strong as ZF. Then it's quite easy to prove the recursion theorem, which allows you to prove the existence and uniqueness of functions on the natural numbers.

The version you need is parametrized:

> Let $E, Y$ be sets, $g: Y \rightarrow E,~ h: E \times Y \rightarrow E$. Then there exists exactly one function $f: \mathbb{N} \times Y \rightarrow E$ such that $f(0, y) = g(y), ~f(n+1, y) = h(f(n, y), y)$.

Now we can derive existence and uniqueness of addition as follows. Let $E = Y = \mathbb{N}$ and let $g$ be the identity function on $\mathbb{N}$ and $h$ that function on $\mathbb{N}$ such that $h(n, m) = Sn$. Then there is a unique function $f$ satisfying the recursion clauses and we can define $n + m := f(m, n)$.

Comment: This assumes that we are working in ZF, as opposed to working with definability inside a structure (e.g. $(\mathbb{N}; \times)$), and I think this isn't what the question is getting at.